# Remove "PHP message" From log

Tags: php, nginx, stderr

I send json message on stderr. Datadog will automatically read all logs from stderr.

The problem is that I received on datadog not a json format but a concanate text of:
"PHP message:" + json data.

So when I do the stderr, it concate automatically.

So how to remove: "PHP message:".

---

I have an nginx system (not apache).